# Android: Save the activity state after a screen rotation

Tags: android, layout, rotation, imageview, screen-rotation

we are working on project in order to create an application to help autits to communicate.

In fact, after moving the ImageViews, all of them are getting back in place after my tablet's rotation.

We tried a lot of things and we finally have made this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.repas);
    area1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.area1);
    area2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.area2);


    TypedArray arrayResources = getResources().obtainTypedArray(
            R.array.resicon);

    if( savedInstanceState != null ) {
        int count_item = savedInstanceState.getInt("number_of_item");
        int tab_item[] = new int[count_item];

        for (int i = 0; i < count_item; i++) {
            tab_item[i]=savedInstanceState.getInt("Sauvegarde_repas" +i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayResources.length(); i++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(arrayResources.getDrawable(i));
            imageView.setOnTouchListener(myOnTouchListener);
            imageView.setId(i);


            if (check(tab_item,i)){
                area1.addView(imageView);
            }
            else{
                area2.addView(imageView);
            }
        }
    }
    else {

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayResources.length(); i++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(arrayResources.getDrawable(i));
            imageView.setOnTouchListener(myOnTouchListener);
            imageView.setId(i);
            area2.addView(imageView);
        }

        arrayResources.recycle();
    }

    area1.setOnDragListener(myOnDragListener);
    area2.setOnDragListener(myOnDragListener);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    int count = area1.getChildCount();
    View v = null;
    outState.putInt("number_of_item", count);
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        v = area1.getChildAt(i);
        outState.putInt("Sauvegarde_repas" + i, v.getId());
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Here are my interrogations:

When I set an id, it's just "i", a very simple number. It doesn't seem very unique like a string "R.id.String_here" (even if I know that is converted in Integer), so how can I be sure to do a unique ID?

Do I have to save, one by one, the child of my layout? It's not possible to save the whole layout?
Do you have any advice to improve my code? (Because it looks dirty, isn't it ?)

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: That's not going to work. You need to save the attributes - location, color, text, whatever you're changing - of the `View`s, not their `toString()` values.

Comment: Thank you for your help !
It's working with id... But how would you do this?

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant by "moving the ImageViews", now. Yeah, I'd do it pretty much like you have it, but you really only need one `for` loop for creating the `ImageView`s.